# Why slice allocator is slower than malloc in glib2.0?

Tags: c, glib

I have wrote two simple programs to compare the speed of *g_slice_alloc()* and *g_malloc()*.

The *g_slice_alloc()* version:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gchar *mem[1000000];
    gint i;
    for(i=0;i<1000000;i++){
        mem[i]=g_slice_alloc(50);
    }
    for(i=0;i<1000000;i++){
       g_slice_free1(50,mem[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

and the *g_malloc()* version

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gchar *mem[1000000];
    gint i;
    for(i=0;i<1000000;i++){
        mem[i]=g_malloc(50);
    }
    for(i=0;i<1000000;i++){
         g_free(mem[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

compile them

```
gcc slice.c -o slice `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-3.0`
gcc malloc.c -o malloc `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-3.0`
```

And test them

```
$ time ./slice

real    0m0.091s
user    0m0.063s
sys 0m0.025s

$ time ./malloc

real    0m0.071s
user    0m0.050s
sys 0m0.021s
```

the *g_slice_alloc()* version is expected to run faster, but in reality it not. Why is it even slower?

Is this a good test case ?

And I tried another way to test their speed.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gchar *mem[1000000];
    gint i;
    for(i=0;i<1000000;i++){
        gint j=i>10000?10000:i;
        mem[i]=g_slice_alloc(j);
    }
    for(i=0;i<1000000;i++){
       gint j=i>10000?10000:i;
       g_slice_free1(j,mem[i]);
    }
   return 0;
}
```

---

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gchar *mem[1000000];
    gint i;
    for(i=0;i<1000000;i++){
         gint j=i>10000?10000:i;
        mem[i]=g_malloc(j);
    }
    for(i=0;i<1000000;i++){
        gint j=i>10000?10000:i;
        g_free(mem[i]);
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

This time they are really close, sometimes *g_slice_alloc()* is faster and somtime *g_malloc()* is faster.

```
$ time ./malloc

real    0m1.515s
user    0m0.285s
sys 0m1.229s

$ time ./slice

real    0m1.521s
user    0m0.278s
sys 0m1.215s
```

But this test doesn't prove *g_slice_alloc()* is faster, it just tells that *g_slice_alloc()* is the same as *g_malloc()*

Comment: It's a guess, but calling a function with 2 arguments (`g_slice_free1(50,mem[i])`) is slower than calling a function with 1 argument (`g_free(mem[i])`), try without `g_free()` in both versions.

Comment: The size argument is a must.  I mean it is a part of slice, so the cost of that arugment is the cost of slice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`glibc`'s malloc has improved *a lot* since `GSlice` was added (when glibc's malloc was notoriously slow).  GSlice used to be a lot faster than malloc, but thanks to aggressive optimization in malloc it is faster these days, especially for heavily threaded applications.  Meanwhile, `GSlice` hasn't really changed significantly since it was added.

AFAIK, these days the only real reason to use `GSlice` is that it is much more stable across different platforms (e.g., apparently Windows' malloc is too slow for GStreamer).

All that said, what you have above isn't really a good test.  What slab-style allocators like `GSlice` have traditionally been good at is reducing memory fragmentation, which is caused by lots of allocations/frees of different sizes mixed together.  What you have is a bunch of allocations followed by a bunch of frees.

Also, allocators like `GSlice` rely on the allocations being the same size, so the portion of the test with incrementing allocation size isn't going to work well—`GSlice` is for objects, not strings and buffers.